# applying pagination to a table in angular js where map is what i'm iterating through in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, hibernate, pagination

i'm iterating through map where key and value pair is there and i'm not getting how to apply pagination of those data where that map data is generated from the database directly.i'm iterating through map where key and value pair is there and i'm not getting how to apply pagination of those data where that map data is generated from the database directly.

```
<table>
            <thead></thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><marquee>
                            <h3>
                                A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with
                                other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier
                                for others to find and answer your question.
                                </h4>
                        </marquee>
                        <hr></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in tagForm.data track by $index">

                    <td align="left">
                        <div ng-init='tagForm.getTag(key)'
                            class=" w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-margin w3-round "
                            style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
                            <br>
                            <p ng-repeat="data2 in tagForm.message track by $index">
                                <a ng-click="tagForm.getAnswer(key)">Q. {{value}}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
                                    class="badge">{{data2}}</span> <br>
                            </p>
                            <ul ng-repeat="(key2,value2) in tagForm.ans track by $index">
                                <li><b ng-if="key==key2">Ans. {{value2}}</b></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div ng-init='tagForm.getUser(key)'>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Posted
                                    by:{{tagForm.user2[$index]}}</b>
                            </div>


                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}"
                                ng-click="count1=count1+1" ng-init="count1=5+($index*3)-5">
                                Upvote <span class="badge">{{count1}}</span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}"
                                ng-click="count=count+1" ng-init="count=1+($index*2)">
                                Downvote<span class="badge">{{count}}</span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotoanswer()">Answer
                                this question</button>
                            <br> <br />
                        </div> <br>
                    </td>

                    <td height=100px><br /></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following pagination in your html file

```
<uib-pagination ng-show="isPaginate == false "
            total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"
            boundary-links="true" items-per-page="numPerPage"
            class="pagination-sm" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="5">
        </uib-pagination>
```

and then initialize the variable as per requirement in angular controller

```
$scope.totalItems = 80;//length of records
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 10;
var startpos = 0;
```

for dynamically loading records (loading records batch wise instead of loading all at time) refer following function

```
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    // if($scope.currentPage!=1)
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    $scope.isRCollapsed = false;
    $scope.page = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
    callApi($scope.page);//get next set of 10 records
    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
};
```